# asp.net Membership : confirmation email blank

Tags: asp.net, membership, registration

I'm using stock Asp.net membership with built in Login controls, etc. Problem is that the confirmation email that is send by registering has a body that is blank. It should have a link in it that the user clicks on to confirm their email and register. The email does send and is delivered ok except the blank body. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ? TIA

Comment: The confirmation e-mail is not a standard feature of ASP.NET membership, so you'll need to provide more details as this sounds like custom code that is having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assigning the content of the message to the message body?

message.Body = "Dear Subscriber, ...";

Comment: This was the closest answer, but essentially when I re-used the wizard that generated the code to set the body it worked. (I had been trying to set the template by hand and it did not work).

Answer (score 0):

make sure your code includes:

message.IsBodyHtml = true;